# How can I add multiple functions to the React js button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to add `startClick` to BackButton as in NextButton. In other words, when the BackButton is clicked, the `startClick` function should work first, then the `dispatch (giveForm2PreviousStep (props.currentStep, props.goToStep))` method should work in order. How can I do that?

**Question JS**

```
const Question = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const loading = useSelector(state => state.app.isLoading)
  const error = useSelector(state => state.app.error)
  const reduxF2 = useSelector(state => state.app.forms.f2)

  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    value: reduxF2.PastReceivables.value,
    valid: true,
  })

  const changeSelected = val => {
    setInput({ ...input, value: val })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setInput({ ...input, value: reduxF2.PastReceivables.value })
  }, [reduxF2.PastReceivables.value])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (reduxF2.bulkSaved && props.currentStep === 2) {
      dispatch(giveForm2NextStep(props.currentStep, props.goToStep))
      dispatch(resetForm2SavedStatus())
    }
  }, [reduxF2.bulkSaved])

  const startClick = e => {
    if (input.value === null || input.value === '') {
      setInput({ ...input, valid: false })
    } else {
      setInput({ ...input, valid: true })
      const questions = getPastReceivablesArray('PastReceivables', input.value, reduxF2)
      if (questions.length == 0) {
        dispatch(giveForm2NextStep(props.currentStep, props.goToStep))
      } else {
        dispatch(updateForm2(questions))
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <MyProgressBar now='8' />
      <Question>Question here</Question>
      <QuestionForm>
        <NumericInput
          valid={input.valid}
          onChange={changeSelected}
          value={input.value}
        />
      </QuestionForm>

      <div className='d-flex justify-content-between'>
        <BackButton onClick={() => dispatch(giveForm2PreviousStep(props.currentStep, props.goToStep))} />
        <NextButton onClick={startClick} loading={loading} />
      </div>
      <Warning error={error} />
    </>
  )
}
```

**BackButton JS**

```
const BackButton = ({ text = 'Back', onClick = null, loading = false, width = '7.5rem' }) => {
  return (
    <Button
      variant='secondary'
      className='back-button'
      onClick={onClick}
      disabled={loading}
      style={{width}}
    >
      <MySpinner loading={loading} />
      {!loading && <>{text}</>}
    </Button>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why not call `dispatch (giveForm2PreviousStep (props.currentStep, props.goToStep))` in `startClick` function?

Comment: const backButtonClick = e => {
      startClick()
      dispatch(giveForm2PreviousStep(props.currentStep, props.goToStep))
  }   I thought this way. I wonder if it would make sense to give this method later in the back button onclick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call multiple functions in onClick event like below

```
<BackButton 
    onClick={(e) => {
        startClick(e);
        dispatch(giveForm2PreviousStep(props.currentStep, props.goToStep))
    }} 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call multiple function in onclick or else you can send call backs to startclick.
so the call backs will be executed after startclick.
easy to give all the fucntions in onClick itself.